# Jquery - Find a word in a string and wrap it with <span> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, indexof

i need to write a function that get a word as arg, find it in a string, and highlight the word with jquery/js only.

```
jsfiddle.net/xzh2qmcd/
```

im already get the word and get the indexOf here, but i dont know how to add a the span tag only where this word appear.

any help we be great, i check some other questions here and cant understand what i should do.

Comment: From the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: Clearly you knew this, though, considering you formatted your jsfiddle link as code to get around that requirement.

Comment: (string, word) => string.replace(word, (w) => `<span>${w}</span>`)

Comment: @floribon - isn't using a function for the replacement overkill? You can just use a string: `"<span>$&</span>"`

Comment: Just use [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)!

Comment: What you are searching for: http://jsfiddle.net/julmot/vpav6tL1/

Comment: Avoid using `innerHTML` (jQuery's `.html()`) method, as this will destroy DOM events and triggers regeneration of the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this :

```
    var txt = textDiv.replace(new RegExp(searchInput, 'gi'), function(str) {
      return "<span class='highlight'>" + str + "</span>"
    });
```

or

```
var txt = textDiv.replace(
                  new RegExp(searchInput, 'gi'), 
                  "<span class='highlight'>$&</span>");
```

`gi` `->` all case insensitive matching text

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // globals
  var searchInput;
  var textDiv;

  $('.searchBtn').click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    // set the values of the search and the text
    searchInput = $('.searchInput').val();
    textDiv = $('.textDiv').text();
    var reg = new RegExp(searchInput, 'gi');
    var txt = textDiv.replace(reg, function(str) {
      return "<span class='highlight'>" + str + "</span>"
    });
    $('.textDiv').html(txt);
  });
});
```

```css
.textDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="searchDiv">
      <h3> Mask A Word In The Text: </h3>
      <label>
        <input class="searchInput" type="text" value = "iS"/> </label>
      <button class="searchBtn" type="button"> Search </button>
    </div>

    <div class="textDiv">
      Bastille Day is the common name given in English-speaking countries to the French National Day, which is celebrated on 14 July each year. In France, it is formally called La fête nationale (French pronunciation: ​[la fɛːt nasjɔnal]; The National Celebration) IS Is
      and commonly Le quatorze juillet. (French pronunciation: ​[lə katɔʁz(ə) ʒɥijɛ]; the fourteenth of July).
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but isn't using a function for the replacement value more complicated than it needs to be? You can just use a string: `"<span>$&</span>"`.

Comment: @nnnnnn You are right, I have add that in my answer. Function on the other hand shows clearly what is going on. and best to learn.

Comment: @HimanshuTyagi : i will suggest to go with full word search otherwise searching is will include English and national will include nationale

Comment: Just a guess on the downvote... see [Easy Money](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251488/211627). Answers to off-topic questions are [commonly downvoted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/191410).

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve the desired using the below code.

I have updated my answer to provide a full word match. I think you will be looking for that only.

example:if you search **national** then it should not color **nationale** word, which will happen if you do not go for a full word search.

```
// search for the input in the paragraph
      if (textDiv.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInput.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
         console.log("match");
         textDiv = textDiv.replace(new RegExp('\\b('+searchInput+')\\b', 'gi'),'<span class="highlight">$1</span>');


       $('.textDiv').html(textDiv);
```

Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/xzh2qmcd/3/

Comment: Some one down voted ? could you let me know the reason?

Comment: Just a guess on the downvote... see [Easy Money](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251488/211627). Answers to off-topic questions are [commonly downvoted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/191410).

Comment: @JDB : OK, I thought there is some mistake in the answer which I couldn't see. However if you a have a look on the fiddle OP provided, it OP tried something on his own but got stuck with replacing the full world in the HTML  string.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   // globals
   var searchInput;
   var textDiv;

   $('.searchBtn').click(function(event) {

      event.preventDefault();

      // set the values of the search and the text
      searchInput = $('.searchInput').val();
      textOfDiv = $('.textDiv').text();

      // search for the input in the paragraph
      if (textOfDiv.indexOf(searchInput) >= 0) {
         console.log("match");
     var newText = textOfDiv.split(searchInput).join('<span class="highlight">' + searchInput + '</span>' );
$('.textDiv').html(newText);
}
      else {
         console.log("no match");
      }
   });
});
```

```css
.textDiv {
    height:100px;
    width:500px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.highlight {
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="searchDiv">
                    <h3> Mask A Word In The Text: </h3>
                    <label> <input class="searchInput" type="text" /> </label>
                    <button class="searchBtn" type="button"> Search </button>
        </div>

        <div class="textDiv">
                Bastille Day is the common name given in
                English-speaking countries to the French National Day,
                which is celebrated on 14 July each year. In France,
                it is formally called La fête nationale (French pronunciation: ​[la fɛːt nasjɔnal]; The National Celebration)
                and commonly Le quatorze juillet.
                (French pronunciation: ​[lə katɔʁz(ə) ʒɥijɛ]; the fourteenth of July).
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   // globals
   var searchInput;
   var textDiv;

   $('.searchBtn').click(function(event) {

      event.preventDefault();

      // set the values of the search and the text
      searchInput = $('.searchInput').val();
      textOfDiv = $('.textDiv').text();

      // search for the input in the paragraph
      if (textOfDiv.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInput) >= 0) {
         console.log("match");
    var newText = textOfDiv.split(searchInput).join('<span class="highlight">' + searchInput + '</span>' );
$('.textDiv').html(newText);
}
      else {
         console.log("no match");
      }
   });
});
```

```css
.textDiv {
    height:100px;
    width:500px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.highlight {
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="searchDiv">
                    <h3> Mask A Word In The Text: </h3>
                    <label> <input class="searchInput" type="text" /> </label>
                    <button class="searchBtn" type="button"> Search </button>
        </div>

        <div class="textDiv">
                Bastille Day is the common name given in
                English-speaking countries to the French National Day,
                which is celebrated on 14 July each year. In France,
                it is formally called La fête nationale (French pronunciation: ​[la fɛːt nasjɔnal]; The National Celebration)
                and commonly Le quatorze juillet.
                (French pronunciation: ​[lə katɔʁz(ə) ʒɥijɛ]; the fourteenth of July).
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```