# jQuery check if letter is in a string and wrap in span tag

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check if a certain character from an array exists in a string, and if true wrap this character in a  tag.

Example:

`<h4>This text contains an X and a P</h4>`

If the array would contain ['x', 'p'] I would like to put a span tag around these two characters, wherever they appear in the string.

I tried to solve this with using pure javascript, but don't want to manipulate the DOM by using innerHTML, so rather use a jQuery solution.

I have tried [Jquery - Find a word in a string and wrap it with <span> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376287/jquery-find-a-word-in-a-string-and-wrap-it-with-span-tag) solution but can't get this working for this case.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, here is a jQuery version

```js
const arr = ["x","p"];
const re = new RegExp(`\\b${arr.join("|")}\\b`,"gi"); // or just /\b[x|p]\b/gi;

$("h4").html((_, text) => text.replace(re, match => `<span>${match}</span>`))
```

```css
h4 span { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>This text contains an X and a P</h4>
```

Vanilla is not much different

```js
const arr = ["x","p"];
const re = new RegExp(`\\b${arr.join("|")}\\b`,"gi"); // or just /\b[x|p]\b/gi;
const h4 = document.querySelector("h4");
h4.innerHTML = h4.textContent.replace(re, match => `<span>${match}</span>`);
```

```css
h4 span { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>This text contains an X and a P</h4>
```